# Webpack Devserver: Open page in browser without typing '.html'

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm making a plain, static site (HTML/CSS/JS) with Webpack that I intend to eventually deploy to s3. I have my final HTML files exported to the root of my dist folder like, *index.html*, *foo.html*, *bar.html*.

When I go to `localhost:9000`, my index loads as expected. For *foo* and *bar* I have to type the file extension like `/foo.html` and `/bar.html` for those pages to load. Is there a setting that I'm missing that will allow me to simply type `/foo` and `/bar` in the browser and have the intended pages load?

Comment: `DevServer` is intended for testing HTML/JS/CSS. It’s not meant to meet your application’s server requirements and isn’t configurable to the point which you require. If you *absolutely* need this functionality, you’ve probably outgrown `DevServer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I found for individual pages, is to specify a proxy using [devServer.proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy). For `/foo` and `/bar`, this would look like that:

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    port: 3000,
    open: false,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
      '/foo': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/foo.html',
        pathRewrite: { '^/foo': '' }
      },
      '/bar': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/bar.html',
        pathRewrite: { '^/bar': '' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check the [DevServer documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nikolai's answer, in case you need your local dev server to serve urls w/o extensions in router **history mode**, just use the following:

```js
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /^\/$/, to: '/views/landing.html' },
        { from: /^\/subpage/, to: '/views/subpage.html' },
        { from: /./, to: '/views/404.html' },
      ],
    },
```

Source: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback